# How to make server not wait on accept after first client?

Tags: c, winapi, network-programming

I have a tcp server and I want to make it so after it accepts the first client it doesn't wait on the accept function and just goes on if no-one else has connected

```
while (1)
    {

        SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(Socket, (sockaddr *)&Client, &ClientSize);
        if(ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            Error("accept failed.\n");
        }
        ClientSockets[ClientSocketsIndex++] = ClientSocket;

        Result = connect(ClientSocket, (sockaddr*)&Client, ClientSize);
    
        sockaddr_in From;
        int FromSize = sizeof(From);
        Result = recv(ClientSocket, Message, sizeof(Message), 0);
        
        if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            Error("recv failed.\n");
        }
        
        Result2 = getpeername(ClientSocket, (sockaddr*)&From, &FromSize);
        if (Result2 == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            Error("getpeername failed.\n");
        }
```

Here I take the ClientSocket with `accept()` and add it to an array where I store all ClientSockets and then receive a buffer. The problem is that after each loop it waits for a new ClientSocket.

The `Error()` function is just a one I made for printing to the console and quitting if I encounter an Error btw.

Comment: Perchance, what do you suspect `Result = connect(ClientSocket, ...` is actually doing in this context? You already *have* a connected socket to your client; it's what was returned from `accept`.

Comment: Umm.. ..move the accept() to above the while loop?

Comment: @MartinJames but if I don't know how many users are going to connect how will I accept the right amount?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you, I forgot to remove it from earlier when I was debugging something and thought this would fix it.

Comment: At a guess, the question you asked and the *real* problem you need to solve aren't the same thing. Presumably, you don't want your `accept` call to block because there's other work you need done. If that is the case, use the Windows Sockets' asynchronous interfaces instead (e.g. `AcceptEx`). [Getting Started with Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock) lists sample code resources. The *iocp* and *overlap* categories are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First off, calling `connect()` on the `SOCKET` returned by `accept()` is wrong.  Get rid of that.

Second, if you want your loop to service multiple clients properly, then use `select()` (or equivalent).  Don't call `accept()` until `select()` tells you that a new client is waiting to be accepted.  Likewise, don't call `recv()` until `select()` tells you that a client in your array is waiting to be read from.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
const size_t MAX_SOCKETS = ...;

SOCKET ClientSockets[MAX_SOCKETS];
size_t NumClientSockets = 0;

...

while (true)
{
    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    FD_SET(Socket, &readfds);
    for(int i = 0; i < NumClientSockets; ++i)
    {
        FD_SET(ClientSockets[i], &readfds);
    }

    if (select(0, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(Socket, &readfds))
        {
            ClientSize = sizeof(Client);
            SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(Socket, (sockaddr *)&Client, &ClientSize);
            if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                Error("accept failed.\n");
            }
            else if (NumClientSockets == MAX_SOCKETS)
            {
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                ClientSockets[NumClientSockets] = ClientSocket;
                ++NumClientSockets;
            }
        }

        size_t i = 0;
        while (i < NumClientSockets)
        {
            if (!FD_ISSET(ClientSockets[i], &readfds))
            {
                ++i;
                continue;
            }

            Result = recv(ClientSockets[i], Message, sizeof(Message), 0);
            if (Result <= 0)
            {
                if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Error("recv failed.\n");

                for(size_t j = i + 1; j < NumClientSockets; ++j)
                {
                    ClientSockets[j - 1] = ClientSockets[j];
                }
                --NumClientSockets;

                continue;
            }

            // use Message up to Result bytes as needed...

            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```